# allow other user to run wiringPiSetupSys()

Tags: wiringpi, sudo, user

I hava e program called outlet in which I communicate out on wiring pin 2 corresponding to BCM-PIN 27 on my Pi:

```
#include "NewRemoteTransmitter.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

NewRemoteTransmitter transmitter(0, 27, 263, 4);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int unitCode = atoi(argv[1]);
    int command  = atoi(argv[2]);
    if(unitCode > 15 || unitCode < 0 || command > 1 || command < 0) return 1;

    if (wiringPiSetupSys() == -1) return 1;

    transmitter.sendUnit(unitCode, command);
    return 0;
}
```

In order to run the small program without being root, I have run `gpio export 27 out` and use `wiringPiSetupSys()` in my program. Running the script as user `pi@raspberrypi` works fine.

But I can't execute the script using a program running as `other@raspberrypi`.

I have unsuccessfully tried to export the pin as `other@raspberrypi` using the following commands:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/ $ sudo -H -u other gpio exports
pi@raspberrypi ~/ $ sudo -H -u other gpio export 27 out
pi@raspberrypi ~/ $ sudo -H -u other gpio exports
GPIO Pins exported:
    27: out  0  none
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -l /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/value
-rw-r--r-- 1 other other 4096 feb  1 07:00 /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/value
```

After doing so, I can't execute the script nor as user `pi` or as `other`.

Any idea of how to make the script executable by user ´other´?

Comment: Are you running a script or a compiled program? More detail will help.

Comment: A small program is probably the correct definition. Se edit of original post.

Comment: I noticed the edit to your post which included the code. There is no point in checking the return code for any of the wiringPiSetup functions - it is always 0.

Comment: @Milliways, thanks for pointing that out. I'll remove that if-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set SUID permission. This allows any user to have permission to owner privileges. There is also a guid option. (This won't work for scripts.)

The `gpio` program has this set.

sudo chmod u+s yourprogram

Comment: Thanks! Don't know what it means but it works :D

Comment: Well, after som thoughts put into this it's a bad solution. The change make the program root which is a possible security issue.

Comment: @sehlstrom There is no security risk. The reason this capability is there is to allow users to run ONLY THIS PROGRAM with elevated privileges. There are already many programs on your Pi which do this e.g. `gpio` and `passwd`. Without `suid` users would be unable to change their own passwords! You write the program so you know what it does! NOTE You cannot set the `suid` on script files, because that may be a security risk as they can be easily changed.

Comment: I have written the program. However, I have not written the wiringpi et al library that I reference. So potentially the libraries can be updated with bad and mean code using it to do bad things with my Pi.